# NHibernate not firing update statement while modifying an existing entity

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql, nhibernate, persistence

I am using NHibernate & Net Persistence API with C# and MySql db in my project and I have UI layer (ASP.NET), Business Layer, and Data Access Layer (DAL). I have the following Save method in UserManager class of DAL:

```
        private EntityManager GetEm()
        {
            if (_entityManager == null)
            {
                _entityManagerFactory = Persistence.CreateEntityManagerFactory("JPUMain");
                _entityManager = _entityManagerFactory.CreateEntityManager();
            }
            return _entityManager;
        }

        public void **Save**(IGenericEntity entity)
        {
            _entityManager = GetEm();
            _entityManager.GetTransaction().Begin();
            _entityManager.Persist(entity);
            _entityManager.Flush();            
            _entityManager.GetTransaction().Commit();            
            _entityManager.Clear();
        }
```

My User entity:

```
 [Entity]
 [Table(Name = "user")]
 public class User : IGenericEntity
    {
        [Id]
        [GeneratedValue]
        public virtual int ID { get; set; }

        [Basic]
        [Column(Name = "fname", Nullable = false)]
        public virtual string FirstName { get; set; }

        [Basic]
        [Column(Name = "lname", Nullable = false)]
        public virtual string LastName { get; set; 
    }
```

Now if I am trying to save user by calling:

```
UserManager.save(user)
```

then it saves the entry to db properly. But say next time (any time, not in the same session) if I try to modify user details, then instead of firing an update command, it fires insert, and it inserts a new record with the modify user entity. I am setting the primary key of user correctly to the modified object.

Also, when I am running test case for the same using NUnit, it is printing following lines:

```
NHibernate: SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()
NHibernate: INSERT INTO user (uid, fname, lname) VALUES (?p0, ?p1, ?p2);?p0 = 2[Type: Int32 (0)], ?p1 = 'First Name' [Type: String (9)], ?p2 = 'Last Name' [Type: String (9)]
```

I tried running this statement directly from phpmyadmin in user table, and it always gives 0 value. I am using InnoDB engine.

Can anyone please tell me that why it is not updating existing user entity? and instead it is creating a new record with the modified entity?

Answer (score 0):

You're saving the entity in another ISession than the ISession you've used to retrieve the entity.

The best thing you can do, is make sure that you're using the same ISession.  I think you should really think on how you're going to manage that.  Sessions should be short-lived, so the best thing is to create some kind of service layer which handles different use cases.

Comment: Even when I am creating a new entity, and then modifying it then and there (within the same method of entity creation) using the same session, it inserts a new record instead of modifying the existing.

Comment: Can you post more code? The case when you are using the same session and get double insert? (including entity manager methods)

Answer (score 0):

Persist never fires an update.

Digging into NH source you may see that Persist, which is really implemented in  [DefaultPersistEventListener](https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/blob/master/src/NHibernate/Event/Default/DefaultPersistEventListener.cs), checks for the state of entity:

```
public class DefaultPersistEventListener : AbstractSaveEventListener, IPersistEventListener
{
    //..
    public virtual void OnPersist(PersistEvent @event, IDictionary createdAlready)
    {
        //... 
        EntityState entityState = GetEntityState(entity, @event.EntityName, source.PersistenceContext.GetEntry(entity), source);

        switch (entityState)
        {
            case EntityState.Persistent:
                EntityIsPersistent(@event, createdAlready);
                break;
            case EntityState.Transient:
                EntityIsTransient(@event, createdAlready);
                break;
            case EntityState.Detached:
                throw new PersistentObjectException("detached entity passed to persist: " + GetLoggableName(@event.EntityName, entity));
            default:
                throw new ObjectDeletedException("deleted instance passed to merge", null, GetLoggableName(@event.EntityName, entity));
        }

}
```

Only method EntityIsTransient submits an insert to the DB. So in the context of session you are doing the update, the entity in question is transient. You should load or attach this entity to the context of session before flushing. SaveOrUpdate method could be an useful shortcut.

Comment: Can you please give some example on how to attach entity to the context of session before flushing?
Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Also Dooh, I am using NPersistence (implementation of NHibernate), and I don't see any SaveOrUpdate method here... How can I achieve this in NPersitence?